# rename columns in a view Oracle

Tags: sql, view, oracle19c

we have a view let's say table1_v

if I run select * from table1_v ,I get an output with a column - Year (Jahr)

I want to know what is the underlying sql so I can find it in Sql developer under details of this view or in all_views.

I wonder because the sql looks like this
select year from table1. such sql will give my the column name YEAR and not Year (Jahr)

I would expect something like this in the view definition -
select year as "Year (Jahr)" from table1

so my question is,where could the column name be renamed if not in the view definition and if it is best practice?

Comment: Why you dont change alias column as you want in view? Anyway you can add alias to selected columns from view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do want to rename it in the view then give the column an alias:

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_name (col1, col2, col3, col4, "Year (Jahr)", col6, col7) AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, year, col5, col6
FROM   table_name;
```

However, don't, as it is not best-practice.

If you want to include mixed-case, spaces and symbol characters in your identifiers then you will need to use a quoted identifier and that means you would need to use the exact same quoted identifier wherever it is reused in queries. Because of the difficulties caused by matching cases, etc. using quoted identifiers is not considered best-practice and you should use unquoted identifiers wherever possible.

> Where could the column name be renamed if not in the view definition and if it is best practice?

Instead of changing the view, you can alias the column when you `SELECT` from the view when you want to **display** the output:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, year AS "Year (Jahr)", col6, col7
FROM   view_name;
```

Comment: Ok that means somebody renamed the column in the create view statement. I would expect when looking the underlying sql for that view but there are just the oroginal column names and not the alias. I think either that this is not a best practice because of using the exact name in quotes if querying and it is tedious but somebody wants to use it in an app with different column names